# Can Eureka registry one service like two different services?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have few micro services and I use eureka for service discovery. I want to split one micro service, but I can't do it from code now(create separate jar). I want to registry one service twice in eureka with same address but different service name. Can I do it?

Comment: Please change your meaningless title to standard English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is No!

Assuming you are using Spring Boot, the Service name is going to be your spring-application-name. Hence, you cannot have more than one name registered from a single Jar

But you have mentioned that you have the constraint that the address should also be same. May be that if that can be relaxed, through Spring Cloud Config you can start multiple instance of your Service with different Profile names and under each profile's config you can override your spring-application-name.